# How to configure PHPEd to run debug from within the subfolder of a workspace?

Tags: php, debugging, phped

To debug a PHP app in PHPEd the root of the project needs to be set to the web folder of my app.

However, the PHP files to be editted are outside of the web folder.

Is it possible to configure PHPEd to run debug from within the /web folder, while displaying all of the PHP files in the workspace?

Desired workspace layout

```
** Workspace Title
**** Project Title
****** Controller files
****** Model files
****** View files
****** Web folder - Debug needs to run from this folder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DebugBreak();` in code to get it to kick into the debugger in PhpEd even if the files are in a weird place in the workspace. (As long as they are in the same project folder, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is to go to the project properties, click on Mapping and then enter the path to the Web folder in the Remote directory and Local directory parts, and URL pointing at the main site.

For example:

`/home/userA/workspace/project/web | X:\home\userA\workspace\project\web | http://www.mysite.com`

Make sure the main project config (the one that points to .../workspace/project) has no URL associated with it (just erase it).